# Rails Devise change "new" path names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way to change the word **new** to **nueva** in 'confirmacion/new' and 'contrasena/new'

```
devise_for :users, path: '',
path_names: {
    sign_in: 'entrar',
    sign_out: 'salir',
    password: 'contrasena',
    confirmation: 'confirmacion',
    unlock: 'desbloquear',
    registration: 'registro',
    new: 'nueva'
}
```

This code just works for the very first path name.

Answer (score 0):

new is a method

you can define the routes specifically like:

```
get '/entrar/neuva' => 'users/sessions#new' as: :your_path_name
```

Also, look into [customizing devise controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

To modify the pathnames in your routes, you would need to replace the default devise routes with your own. You can use the `path_names` attribute to achieve this:

You should be able to wrap your devise routes with a scope to achieve this:

```
scope(path_names: { new: ‘nueva’, edit: ‘editar ’ }) do
  devise_for :users
end
```

For more information, check out sections `4.4` and `4.7` of the rails guide on routing:

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-the-new-and-edit-segments